# Why sometimes 'this' works and sometimes doesn't in Vue template?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Have a situation in which there are two different components, that have templates in which there are 'this' used. Removing all 'this' from templates right now, but saw this situation and got curios why it is happening like this.

In this case it throws error:

```
<a :href="`${this.$locale() ? "Yes" : "No}`">
```

In this case it works:

```
<title :lang="this.$locale()">
```

These are just examples, but is there a reason that one works and other throws error? Couldn't find any information on this in Vue documentation. Could this be because of ternary operation?

Comment: Please, be more specific, what error?

Comment: I guess it comes from the ``${` wrapper. The tenary operator should be fine. In addition I have never see someone using `this` in the template....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to be clear for the people reading this, you shouldn't use `this` inside Vue SFC templates.

To anwser, that's because of how Vue compiles your template and its properties. I'm not an expert on Vue internal mecanics so please take what I say with caution.

`:lang="this.$locale()` Here, it could be that Vue removes the `this` reference at build time.

`` :href="`${this.$locale() ? "Yes" : "No}`" `` Here you're using a string interpolation, which is evaluated at runtime. Vue has no way to remove the `this` safely, because it could be refering to something else than the component instance. So `this` just stays as is in the final bundle and breaks at runtime.

This is just my guess from my understanding of Vue. I think only a Vue maintainer / contributor could anwser this properly.

Comment: `this` is needed in templates to refer to dynamic properties. Better to use computeds but any way, the use of `this` is legit there.