# How to utilize a callback in a conditional in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, conditional-formatting

I need to change the focus styling in vueJS i have a call that find a focused element but I simply cant use it straight up in conditional rendering so I used a callback but I cant get the callback to work in the in line styling.

```
<template>
   <button
            ...
            :style="this.isThisElementActive() ? {'border':'solid 2px blue'} : ''"
            ref="shipToStoreZipCodeButton"
          >
            {{ locationName }}
          </button>
</template>


export default {
...
methods:{
...  isThisElementActive(){
      console.log(document.activeElement,this.$refs.shipToStoreZipCodeButton)
      return document.activeElement === this.$refs.shipToStoreZipCodeButton
    },
}
```

Comment: This isn't directly related to the message, but I would strongly suggest looking at the Vue3 Composition API

Answer (score 0):

In the template, you shouldn't use `this`

```
<template>
<button
        ...
    :style="isThisElementActive() ? {'border':'solid 2px blue'} : ''"
            ref="shipToStoreZipCodeButton"
          >
            {{ locationName }}
          </button>
 </template>
```

As this may cause unexpected bugs in runtime.

Question referance.
[Why sometimes 'this' works and sometimes doesn't in Vue template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68457095/why-sometimes-this-works-and-sometimes-doesnt-in-vue-template)

Also, it would be better to use `computed` instead, as `isThisElementActive` function doesn't take any parameter.

Comment: actually I don't recall any "shouldn't use `this`" part in the docs. apart from that, "no need to use `this` in the template" is much more accurate. but shouldn't is just an exaggeration. if you have any proof, then you *should* share that in the answer too...

Comment: `this` may lead to unexpected bugs on runtime, have a look at this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68457095/why-sometimes-this-works-and-sometimes-doesnt-in-vue-template

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by using the `:focus` pseudo class :

```html
<template>
   <button class="my-btn"  >
            {{ locationName }}
    </button>
</template>
<style>
.my-btn:focus{
  border: solid 2px blue
}
</style>
```